# Change default upload images size for contributors

Tags: functions

When a contributor uploads an image to a post, the default image size option is set to Medium. How can I change it to Large or Full?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default image size for inserting images is stored in the options table in `image_default_size`. You can change the default image size by updating the option:

```
update_option( 'image_default_size', 'large' );
```

### Role-dependent default image size

To change the default image size for contributors only, you could hook into `pre_option_[option]` filter (which is fired directly after sanitizing the option name passed to `get_option`, giving you the possibility to change the value returned by `get_option`) and return another image size for contributors only:

```
function myplugin_contributor_image_default_size( $value ) {
    if ( current_user_can( 'contributor' ) ) {
        return 'large';
    }

    return $value;
}


add_filter( 'pre_option_image_default_size', 'myplugin_contributor_image_default_size' );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function mytheme_setup() {
    // Set default values for the upload media box
    update_option('image_default_align', 'center' );
    update_option('image_default_link_type', 'media' );
    update_option('image_default_size', 'large' );

}
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'mytheme_setup');
```